# WinSCP connect to Ubuntu. Access Denied

Tags: ubuntu, winscp

I installed Ubuntu13_desktop in VMware(VMware® Workstation 7.1.6) based with Windows 7.
Now I want to connect to Ubuntu from Windows 7.
Set the WMware as **Host-only**. 
Installed WinSCP in Windows, configured

```
protocol: SFTP;
Host name: ubuntu;
Port: 22;
UserName: oracle;
Password: ***.
```

Clicked Login, it showed

```
Searching for host...
Connection to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "oracle"
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Access denied.
Access denied.
```

I can succeed to ping Ubuntu by cmd.

Can anyone help me to let me access Ubuntu by WinSCP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is off-topic for stackoverflow. It belongs on superuser instead.

Comment: I'm sorry?  Would you mind telling why it is off-topic?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying connect to Ubuntu machine from windows machine.

Comment: What did you do to setup the `oracle` account?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I followed this post: [srmklive.com](http://blog.srmklive.com/2013/04/24/how-to-setup-sftp-server-ftp-over-ssh-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: Can you login with that account locally on the Ubuntu machine? Did you check SSH server log?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, yes, I can login with that account, and when I use WinSCP to connect Ubuntu, syslog in Ubuntu didn't change any more.

Comment: There has to be some record of the login attempt somewhere.

Comment: my experience with this problem is Leap 15.1 has no option for SSH.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well the port 22 is for SSH service. So you can probably try installing openssh-server in your ubuntu by typing

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

and then try connecting with the following details:

protocol: SSH

hostname: [IP Address of the computer]

port: 22

username: [username]

password: [password]

Hopefully this should work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you advise. I did `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`. But it still doesn't make sense.  Now, I installed FileZilla in Windows, it prompted `Status: Connecting to 10.112.20.229...
Response: fzSftp started
Command: open "oracle@10.112.20.229" 22
Error: Network error: Connection refused
Error: Could not connect to server`

Comment: And the problem became more serious. By WinSCP, it prompts `The server rejected SFTP connection, but it listens for FTP connections.

Did you want to use FTP protocol instead of SFTP? Prefer using encryption.`

Comment: For a reference, the above problem was asked here: [The server rejected SFTP connection, but it listens for FTP connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965425/the-server-rejected-sftp-connection-but-it-listens-for-ftp-connections)

Answer (score 2):

First look at `auth.log` on the system.

```
cat /var/log/auth.log
```

In my case with **WinSCP**, I found something like this:

```
fatal: no matching mac found: client hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5 server hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160 [preauth]
```

And comment the line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
```

don't forget to restart ssh :-)
Hope this can help some one.

Comment: Thank you, this workaround worked for me, but it would be good if somebody can elaborte on the security implications of this,

Answer (score 0):

If sshd (openssh-server) is installed and running, but still no access when using WinSCP.  In Ubuntu 16.x look at the auth logs:

```
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log
```

I found this:

```
No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
```

The problem is Ubuntu sshd configuration defaults to public/private key authentication for remote ssh access:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

If you want to skip the kay-pair work, Open the sshd conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find the above attributes and modify to:

```
RSAAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

restart sshd:

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

If you have set up a user on the Ubuntu 16.x instance, you now should be able to ssh or WinSCP with username/password.  Please be aware that the security of the system is now at greater risk.